# How to properly replace database in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, database, database-connection

I want to connect my Magento 2 to a new database, I've updated the `/app/etc/env.php`
What other steps do I need to take

Answer (score 1):

The following steps, you need to perform to properly replace the database:

- Change connectivity parameters for the new database in app/etc/env.php
- Check and correct base URLs in the core_config_data table in the new database.
- Since there may be a difference in the entries of setup_module table, you must run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** to map all existing modules (with correct version) to the new database.

Note that above steps are necessary. Below steps may be optional:

- Clean cache.
- Compile and deploy the static content.